# Captcha is not working on CD

Tags: wffm

I am using WFFM (9.0 rev. 171209 Update-1) on sitecore 9. I am facing a strange issue on CD environment.

When user submit the from it's showing an error message(screenshot attached), while it's perfectly working on other environments.

[image]

I have double-checked all the configurations on respective environments.

Could anyone suggest what is being missed...

Comment: Without the error message, this will be hard to answer..

Comment: there is not any logs as such which could help me to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Check your new environment domain name is configured with captcha key.